# What is a faster option to compare vales in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to structure a df for productivity at some point i need to verify if a id exist in list and give a indicator in function of that, but its too slow (something like 30 seg for df).

can you enlighten me on a better way to do it?

thats my current code:

```
data['first_time_it_happen'] = data['id'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x in old_data['id'].values else 1)
```

(i already try to use the colume like a serie but it do not work correctly)

Comment: " i need to verify if a id exist in list" That will always be slow. Don't use a `list`, use a `set`. `.apply` is also slow. Use `data['id'].isin(values)`. I believe that may convert it to a set underneath the hood.

Comment: Actually, looking at the source code, I think it always converts to a 1d numpy array and uses `np.in1d` or a bespoke hash-based solution based on the type and size. In any case, `data['id'].isin(old_data['id'])` will definitely be faster.

Comment: What would also almost certainly be faster is simply `old = set(old_data['id'].values); data['first_time_it_happen'] = [x in old for x in data['id']]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To settle some debate in the comment section, I ran some timings.

Methods to time:

```
def isin(df, old_data):
    return df["id"].isin(old_data["id"])

def apply(df, old_data):
    return df['id'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x in old_data['id'].values else 1)

def set_(df, old_data):
    old = set(old_data['id'].values)
    return [x in old for x in df['id']]
```

```
import pandas as pd
import string

old_data = pd.DataFrame({"id": list(string.ascii_lowercase[:15])})
df = pd.DataFrame({"id": list(string.ascii_lowercase)})
```

Small DataFrame tests:

```
# Tests ran in jupyter notebook
%timeit isin(df, old_data)
184 µs ± 5.03 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

%timeit apply(df, old_data)
926 µs ± 64.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit set_(df, old_data)
28.8 µs ± 1.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Large dataframe tests:

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 100000, ignore_index=True)

%timeit isin(df, old_data)
122 ms ± 22.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit apply(df, old_data)
56.9 s ± 6.37 s per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit set_(df, old_data)
974 ms ± 15 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Seems like the `set` method is a smidge faster than the `isin` method for a small dataframe. However that comparison radically flips for a much larger dataframe. Seems like in most cases the `isin` method is will be the best way to go. Then the `apply` method is always the slowest of the bunch regardless of dataframe size.

Comment: Hi guys, thanks a lot for help, i decide to use the set method, because give a balance between speed and set a value in place. (in1d  resulted on a interesting thing that i didnt now)